# how to set a link depends on value in database column

Tags: php

i want set a link in html table. lets say jone have 100 point and it will show `$url2` or him and lina have 90 point and it will show `$url1`.

this is my broken code. i don't know how to make it. and pls tell me where are my mistake.

```
<td>
<? 
        if ( (int)$jumlah_bv < 100 ){


echo "<a class="btn btn-info" href="buy1.php?user_id= echo $row['user_id']; " >Daftar VIP</a>";
 }
 else 
 {

echo "<a class="btn btn-info" href="buy2.php?user_id= echo $row['user_id']; " >Belian</a>";
 }

    ?>      
    </td>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `$url2` into the `else` block?

Comment: You only assign in the `if`, not the `else`. You could simplify this with ternary, `$page = $point < 100 ? '1' : '2';` then use `$page` in place of the numbers in your HTML.

Comment: @rickdenhaan no. why sir?

Comment: wait @chris85 sir. i try your code

Comment: `"<a class="btn btn-info"` is incorrect, it must be `"<a class=\"btn btn-info\"` etc...

Comment: Yes, that is also true. You need to clarify, "broken", you are getting an error, or incorrect display? You can't run an `echo` in an assignment.

Comment: sir, check my question

Comment: @chris85 i got incorrect display. i just want to print url depend on point value in database column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is off, you only assign and output in the `if` condition. Read it as the processor would

if $point is less than 100 execute the following lines:

```
$url1 = "<a class="btn btn-info" href="url1.php?user_id= echo $row['user_id']; " >this is url 1</a>";
$url2 = "<a class="btn btn-info" href="url2.php?user_id= echo $row['user_id']; " >this is url 2</a>";
echo $url1;
```

if not execute these lines:

```
echo $url2;
```

as you can see the `$url2` is undefined here. A simpler way I think would be with ternary:

```
$page = $point < 100 ? '1' : '2';
echo "<a class='btn btn-info' href='url{$page}.php?user_id={$row['user_id']}'>this is url {$page}</a>";
```

You also had incorrect quote usage and were trying to output in an assignment.

**Update, per revised question:**

```
if($point < 100) {
      $page = 'page1.php';
      $text = 'page 1 text';
} else {
      $page = 'page2.php';
      $text = 'page 2 text';
} 
echo "<a class='btn btn-info' href='{$page}?user_id={$row['user_id']}'>{$text}</a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? To me the main problem seemed like you assigning both URL-variables inside the `if` rather than outside.

```
<td>
<?php
    $url1 = "buy1.php";
    $url2 = "buy2.php";
    $href = "";
    $linktext = "";

    if ( $jumlah_bv < 100 ){
        $href = $url1;
        $linktext = "Daftar VIP";
    }
    else 
    {
        $href = $url2;
        $linktext = "Belian";
    }
    echo '<a class="btn btn-info" href="'. $href .'?user_id='. $row['user_id'] .'">'. $linktext .'</a>';
?>
</td>
```